# Adding a secondary axis to ggplot2 ggridges (joyplot) to show counts in each bin

Tags: r, ggplot2, ridgeline-plot, ggridges

I have a ridge plot made with the `ggridges` package, using the `stat = 'binline'` argument to plot a histogram for each group. I would like to show the counts for each group on a secondary y-axis at left, with at least one or two axis ticks per group. I cannot find any examples where this has been done. I know it is not straightforward because of the way the y-axis is constructed in `ggridges`. Is there a relatively easy way to do this?

### Code:

```
set.seed(1)
fakedat <- data.frame(x = sample(1:10, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                      g = letters[1:4])

library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

ggplot(fakedat, aes(x = x, y = g)) +
  geom_density_ridges(stat = 'binline', bins = 10, scale = 0.9) +
  theme_ridges()
```

### Plot:

[image]

Desired output would be to have ticks going up the left side that begin at zero at the baseline of each group and show the counts in the histogram bins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're doing this the hard way. Effectively, what you are trying to do is faceted histograms. Here's a full reprex with a very similar look that doesn't use `ggridges` at all:

```r
set.seed(1)
fakedat <- data.frame(x = sample(1:10, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                      g = factor(letters[1:4], letters[4:1]))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(fakedat, aes(x = x, y = ..count..)) +
  stat_bin(geom = "col",  breaks = 0:11 - 0.5, fill = "gray70") +
  stat_bin(geom = "step", breaks = 0:13 - 1) +
  facet_grid(g ~ ., switch = "y") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:4 * 3) +
  theme(strip.background    = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x         = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.line.x         = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x        = element_line(colour = "gray90"),
        axis.ticks.length.x = unit(30, "points"),
        strip.text.y.left   = element_text(angle = 0, size = 16),
        panel.grid.major.x  = element_line(colour = "gray90"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It will be a shame to give up some of the nice built-in options from ggridges but this definitely does the trick!

Comment: @qdread ggridges is a very nice package and can do some things you just can't do easily in ggplot, but the reverse is also true!